# Find $a$, $b$ such that the ellipse $(x/a)^2 + (y/b)^2 = 1$ passes through $(\sqrt 2, 2)$ and has minimum area

Tags: optimization, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, constraints

I am working on a problem in which, for $a$, $b \gt 0$, we let $(x/a)^2 + (y/b)^2 = 1$ describe an ellipse.
I am required to use the method of Lagrange multipliers and the corresponding second derivative test to find $a$ and $b$ such that the ellipse passes through $(x, y) = (\sqrt 2, 2)$ and such that the area of the ellipse $A = \pi ab$ is minimised amongst all such ellipses.

My thoughts:

Firstly, since $(\sqrt 2, 2)$ lies on the ellipse, we must have that

$$\frac{2}{a^2} + \frac{4}{b^2} = 1.$$

Secondly, I let $g(a, b) = \pi ab$.
With the aim of minimising this function, I calculated $g_a = \pi b$ and $g_b = \pi a$ and set them both equal to $0$.
However, this only gives that $a = b = 0$, which is not allowed.

I am not yet sure how to progress further with this question and would appreciate **hints**.

Comment: Do you know about the Lagrange multiplier?

Comment: @Dylan: Yes, I do.  I know that it is used in a situation when we have a function, say $f$, constrained to some set, say $C$, and we want to find the extrema of $f$.

Comment: Use that. Your constraint is the ellipse and your minimization function is the area.

Comment: Are you allowed to minimize $uv$ given that $u+v=uv/8$ where $0<u=2a^2 $ and $0<v=4a^2$?

Comment: @user254665: How would this help?

Comment: Less stuff to compute when differentiating.As in the method in Dylan's solution ,we get $1=-\lambda v/8 =-\lambda u/8$. Since the Q was to test your skill in Lagrange's method, not to find the least area by  other means, so I can't tell how much simplification is allowed, considering that the least area can be found by elementary algebra.

Comment: @user254665: Ah, I understand.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constraint function is 
$$ f(a,b) = \frac{2}{a^2} + \frac{4}{b^2} - 1 $$
and your minimization function is $g(a,b) = \pi ab$

Using the Lagrange multiplier method, this requires $\nabla g = \lambda \nabla f $, thus we have the following system

$$ \pi b = -\lambda\frac{4}{a^3} $$
$$ \pi a = -\lambda\frac{8}{b^3} $$
$$ f(a,b) = 0 $$

Comment: When I apply this method, I find four critical points: $(a, b) = (\pm 2, \pm 2\sqrt 2)$.  I then try to use the bordered Hessian matrix, $\bar{\text H}$ to classify these critical points.  However, when I take the point $(a, b) = (2, 2\sqrt 2)$, for example, I get that $\det\bar{\text H}(2, 2\sqrt 2)$  depends on $\lambda$, my Lagrangian multiplier.  How, then, can I tell whether or not $\det\bar{\text H}(2, 2\sqrt 2)$ is greater than, less than or equal to $0$, seeing as I don't know the value of $\lambda$?

Comment: Don't overthink it. $a$ and $b$ are positive, so there's really only one solution

Comment: Of course!  Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't Lagrange method give the stationary points? Don't we need to check if the points are indeed min values?

Answer (score 0):

HINT: use the Lagrange Multiplier method
$$F=\pi ab+\lambda(\frac{2}{a^2}+\frac{4}{b^2}-1)$$